# How can I make an array of values after duplicate keys in a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a question regarding duplicate keys in hashes.
Say my dataset looks something like this:

```
>Mammals
Cats
>Fish
Clownfish
>Birds
Parrots
>Mammals
Dogs
>Reptiles
Snakes
>Reptiles
Snakes
```

What I would like to get out of my script is a hash that looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Birds' => 'Parrots',
          'Mammals' => 'Dogs', 'Cats',
          'Fish' => 'Clownfish',
          'Reptiles' => 'Snakes'
        };
```

I found a possible answer here (https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1116320). However I am not sure how to identify the values and the duplicates with the format of my dataset.

Here's the code that I have been using:

```
use Data::Dumper;
    open($fh, "<", $file) || die "Could not open file $file $!/n";

    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        if($_ =~ /^>(.+)/){
            $group = $1; 
            $animals{$group} = ""; 
            next;

        }
        $animals{$group} .= $_;   
push @{$group (keys %animals)}, $animals{$group};

    }
print  Dumper(\%animals);
```

When I execute it the push function does not seem to work as the output from this command is the same as when the command is absent (in the duplicate "Mammal" group, it will replace the cat with the dog instead of having both as arrays within the same group).

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Read two lines at a time. Create a HoH (`++$animals{$group}{$thing};`), then flatten after you've read everything in (`$_ = join(", ", @$_) for values(%animals);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close here. We can't get exactly the output you want from `Data::Dumper` because hashes can only have one value per key. The easiest way to fix that is to assign a reference to an array to the key and add things to it. But since you want to eliminate the duplicates as well, it's easier to build hashes as an intermediate representation then transform them to arrays:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $file = "animals.txt";
open($fh, "<", $file) || die "Could not open file $file $!/n";

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if(/^>(.+)/){
        $group = $1; 
        next;
    }
    $animals{$group} = {} unless exists $animals{$group};
    $animals{$group}->{$_} = 1;
}

# Transform the hashes to arrays
foreach my $group (keys %animals) {
  # Make the hash into an array of its keys
  $animals{$group} = [ sort keys %{$animals{$group}} ];
  # Throw away the array if we only have one thing
  $animals{$group} = $animals{$group}->[0] if @{ $animals{$group} } == 1;
}
print  Dumper(\%animals);
```

Result is

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Reptiles' => 'Snakes',
          'Fish' => 'Clownfish',
          'Birds' => 'Parrots',
          'Mammals' => [
                         'Cats',
                         'Dogs'
                       ]
        };
```

which is as close as you can get to what you had as your desired output.

For ease in processing the ingested data, it may actually be easier to *not* throw away the arrays in the one-element case so that every entry in the hash can be processed the same way (they're all references to arrays, no matter how many things are in them). Otherwise you've added a conditional to strip out the arrays, and you have to add another conditional test in your processing code to check

```
if (ref $item) {
    # This is an anonymous array
} else {
    # This is just a single entry
}
```

and it's easier to just have one path there instead of two, even if the `else` just wraps the single item into an array again. Leave them as arrays (delete the `$animals{$group} = $animals{$group}->[0]` line) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
__DATA__
>Mammals
Cats
>Fish
Clownfish
>Birds
Parrots
>Mammals
Dogs
>Reptiles
Snakes
>Reptiles
Snakes
```

(at the end of the source code or a file with that content)

If you are willing to *slurp* the file, you can do something with a regex and a HoH like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
use strict;
my %animals;
my $s;

while(<DATA>){
    $s.=$_;
}    

while($s=~/^>(.*)\R(.*)/mg){
    ++$animals{$1}{$2};
}

print Dumper(\%animals);
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Mammals' => {
                         'Cats' => 1,
                         'Dogs' => 1
                       },
          'Birds' => {
                       'Parrots' => 1
                     },
          'Fish' => {
                      'Clownfish' => 1
                    },
          'Reptiles' => {
                          'Snakes' => 2
                        }
        };
```

Which you can arrive to your format with this complete Perl program:

```
$s.=$_ while(<DATA>);
++$animals{$1}{$2} while($s=~/^>(.*)\R(.*)/mg);
while ((my $k, my $v) =  each (%animals)) {
    print "$k: ". join(", ", keys($v)) . "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Fish: Clownfish
Birds: Parrots
Mammals: Cats, Dogs
Reptiles: Snakes
```

(Know that the output order may be different than file order since Perl hashes do not maintain insertion order...)